# How to std::bind a class function properly?

Tags: c++, class, object, callback

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    void Func1(int,int);
    void Func2(long,long);
private:
    ...
};

<implementation here>
```

In main:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> fl;
A a;
fl.push_back(std::bind(&a.Func1, 1,1));
```

Gives the error:
ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function

Solution?

Edit: changed "A a();" to "A a;". No constructor here :P

Edit:
Selected Praetorian's reply as answer because it solves the problem.
Dietmar Kühl's is a good solution too but not the actual answer to the question.
Gotta be fair :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Func1` is a non-static member function, so it must be invoked on an instance of `A`, which you'll need to `bind` as the first argument (the `this` pointer). Also, when creating a pointer to member function, the syntax is `&ClassName::MemFuncName`.

So you need

```
fl.push_back(std::bind(&A::Func1, &a, 1, 1));
```

Make sure that the lifetime of `a` does not end before you invoke the bound function.

Comment: Okay, so if I have  A a;  A b;  A c;  A d;  and want to bind all of them, the correct way would be to use the line you wrote above, but change "&a" to "&b" and the others accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues. First,

```
A a();
```

is a function declaration. You need

```
A a;
```

Then,

```
fl.push_back(std::bind(&A::Func1, &a, 1,1));
```

Comment: I believe you would need to add an extra `&` before `A::Func1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just not use `std::bind()`:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> fl;
A a{};
fl.push_back([&](){ a.Func1(1, 1); });
```

The code show references `a` on the stack. That's OK when the function object doesn't outlive `a`. If that can't be guaranteed you may want to replace the `&` by `=` which would copy the object. BTW, the subtle change from `()` to `{}` causes the code to declare `a` an object of type `A` rather than as a function taking no argument and returning `A`.

Comment: Okay, is there any difference? Advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: @Solrik: Difference between what? `std::bind()` vs. a lambda function? The lambda function has the advantage that the call doesn't go through a function pointer and has a better chance of getting inlined. Not that this will be a major difference as `std::function<...>` will do a `virtual` call (or something equivalent) anyway. Also, the lambda function will copy all bound/captured arguments just once while it depends on the implementation of `std::bind()` how often bound arguments are copied (I don't know how good contemporary implementations are).

Comment: What type would v be?

Comment: That's, obviously, your `std::vector<std::function<void(void)>>`. Seems you called it `fl` (I shall update the answer).

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately C++ doesn't have a syntax like that. A complete example with the correct syntax would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    void Func1(int,int) {}
    void Func2(long,long) {}
};


int main() 
{

    std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> fl;
    A a;
    fl.push_back(std::bind(&A::Func1, &a, 1,1));
    return 0;
}
```

You need to provide two things (at least): 1) the pointer to member function 2) the implicit "this" pointer, i.e., the object you want to call the method on.

Then you can add the parameters you want to bind.

Note also that unfortunately you can't make an instance of "A" with "A a();" This is the "most vexing parse". The correct way is "A a;" or "A a{};"