# C++ callback using std::bind

Tags: c++, callback

I am trying to use callback to create a window that is a member function which has access to class members:

```
class A
{
   public:
   A();
   LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
   
};

A::A()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    auto callback = std::bind(&A::WndProc, this, _1);
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_CLASSDC, callback, 0L, 0L, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, _T("Example"), NULL };
}
```

and Im getting this error:
[image]

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,LRESULT (__cdecl A::* )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM),A *,const std::_Ph<1> &>' to 'WNDPROC'
```

I do not understand what is wrong here, Im trying to do it from examples from similar questions, but I think I do not really understand what is happening here

Comment: Apart from the image, add the text of the error as well.

Comment: Also you may want to add link to the example that you're adapting from

Comment: [c++ - How to std::bind a class function properly? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514656/how-to-stdbind-a-class-function-properly): https://stackoverflow.com/a/27514711/5267751

Comment: @Ruks because it also need "this" parameter, when Im tryin to do that happens similar error:  error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__cdecl A::* )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'WNDPROC'

Answer (score 0):

[`WNDCLASSEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw) is a struct from the WinAPI that accepts its callback as a [`WNDPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-wndproc) which is a function pointer alias type.

Now, the return value of `std::bind()` isn't a function pointer object and isn't convertible to one either. You may want to look at this question: [convert std::bind to function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238050/convert-stdbind-to-function-pointer) for a workaround.

However, the straightforward solution to your problem is to **not** use `std::bind()` and to make `WndProc()` a `static` method instead:

```cpp
class A
{
   public:
   A();
   static LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
   
};

A::A()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_CLASSDC, &A::WndProc, 0L, 0L, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, _T("Example"), NULL };
}
```